# Making batch requests with Node/Express JS

Tags: node.js, express

I have an endpoint `/myEndpoint` where I need to process batch requests.

For example, let's say I have an array with 1000+ URLs

```
const URLs = ['/url1','/url2','/url3',
'/url4','/url5','/url6',
'/url7','/url8','/url9',
'/url10','/url11','/url12',
...]
```

For each url I will need to execute a "POST" request but I want to be sure every requests has been fired before my expressJS function (`/myEndpoint`) terminate knowing that **I am in a serverless environment**.

So, which is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Is your endpoint listening to those urls ? (eg /myEnpoint/:xxx) or are they related ? or is the urls in the payload of the call to myEndpoint ?

Comment: Do you care for the result of the requests or do you just want to fire and forget?